# Use srec_cat to join three binaries and fill holes

Tags: embedded, binaryfiles, srec-cat

I have three binaries for specific memory addresses that I want to combine with `srec_cat` filling the holes with 0xFF.

- bootloader.bin —> 0x1000
- conf.bin —> 0x8000
- app.bin —> 0x10000

**Memory map**

```
|- pad w/ 0xFF -|- *bootloader* ~~~ pad w/ 0xFF -|- *conf* ~~~ pad w/ 0xFF -| - *app* ~~~|
0            0x1000                           0x8000                    0x10000
```

`~~~` signifies a "fluid" boundary i.e. the binary to the left of it doesn't have a fixed size.

**CLI arguments**

I am a bit lost between the `−fill`, `-binary` and `-offset` options that I read about on http://srecord.sourceforge.net/man/man1/srec_examples.html#BINARY%20FILES. Is there a way to tell `srec_cat` to fill anything between 0x1000 and 0x8000 that is **not** occupied by `bootloader.bin` (regardless of what size the .bin actually has)?

Comment: Does this work:  `srec_cat bootloader.bin -Binary -fill 0xFF 0x00000000 0x00008000 conf.bin -Binary -offset 0x00008000 -o combined.bin -Binary`?

Comment: I will try once the test environment is fixed but it "looks" wrong. `bootloader.bin` needs to be at offset 0x1000. Is the general idea to first fill from 0x0 to 0x10000 then cat bootloader at offset 0x1000, then cat conf at offset 0x8000 and then cat the app at the end?

Comment: Out of pure interest: are you doing this from inside a makefile?

Comment: No, as post process of what a 3rd-party Makefile produced ;-)

Comment: I also tried the "first fill 0xFF up to 0x10000 and then overwrite" approach but `srec_cat` doesn't support that: `contradictory 0x00008000 value (previous = 0xFF, this one = 0xAA)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried this myself and I believe this will do what you want.

```
srec_cat bootloader.bin -Binary -offset 0x00001000 -fill 0xff 0x00000000 0x00008000 conf.bin -Binary -offset 0x00008000 -fill 0xff 0x00008000 0x00010000 app.bin -Binary -offset 0x00010000 -o combined.bin -Binary
```